# Component YiiBooster datepickerRow does not show calendar

Tags: yii-components

I'm newie developing with Yii PHP framework and YiiBootstrap, I have a problem when I'm trying to use the datepickerRow component, the calendar does not showed when the cursor focus the field. Somebody know why?. This is the code that I'm using.

```
<?php echo $form->datepickerRow($model, 'publication_date',
        array('prepend'=>'<i class="icon-calendar"></i>' 
                , 'options'=>array( 'format' => 'dd/mm/yyyy', 
                                    'weekStart'=> 1,)
)
);
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Because the Calendar shows on click not on focus for more info http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/